# Annotations in TexStudio

Tags: texstudio, annotations

Somehow I just created an "annotation" window in TexStudio. I have been using TexStudio for about 4 years and never knew this was possible. I cannot find anything in the online documentation for TexStudio that even mentions the word "annotation". Annotation shows up as an option in the "Window" menu when the pdf window is selected. It seems like this might be a useful feature but I would like to know "how" I created this one window and what properties it might have.

Comment: samcarter -- thanks -- but my problem is figuring out how to create an annotation in the first place. Apparently by some sort of random action (me and the monkeys at the typewriters) I created one but I have no idea how.

Answer (score 3):

Annotations are a feature of PDF. TeXstudio can display the annotations in a PDF. It does not support editing the PDF (and annotations therein). This would be rather pointless anyway, because the PDF gets recompiled and changes would be lost.

Instead, you can use LaTeX packages like `todonotes` to create annotations.

See [here for an example](https://sourceforge.net/p/texstudio/feature-requests/418/#f51b).

[image]

As an additional feature, TeXstudio can show a list of annotations in an PDF (not shown in the screenshot). This can also be used in a review process.

1. Give the PDF to a reviewer
2. He can add annotations with whatever tool he likes (e.g. Adobe Acrobat).
3. Replace the PDF in your tex document folder by the annotated pdf.
4. View the PDF in TeXstudio (don't recompile. That would overwrite the pdf).
5. Browse the list of annotations: Clicking on the annotation brings up the Position in the PDF. Ctrl-Click in the PDF moves to the source code. Here you can directly fix something or add a comment / `%TODO`yourself for later handling. Syncing will work as long as you don't recompile.

Answer (score 1):

Right click in the pdf will give you the following context menu:

[image]